# How to consume cucumber step class from imported library?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-spring

I made a java lib project with all steps classes to be used in other project

```
package ulala.aop.integration.steps;

public class KafkaSteps {

@Autowired
private BinderAwareChannelResolver resolver;

@Autowired
private MessageChannel localOutput, throttlingOutput;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private MessageBuilder messageBuilder;

private MessageChannel messageChannel;

private String message;

@Given("{string} topic destination to notify")
public void kafkaServerWithTopic(String destination) {

    messageChannel = resolver.resolveDestination(destination);

}
...
```

The configuration is the follow

```
package ulala.aop.integration.boot;
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberConfiguration {
}
```

I added the dependency on the main spring-boot project. The project has a rest controller , the features.

On the rest class I execute the feature like this

```
String response = String.valueOf(Main.run(new String[]{"--glue",
                        "ulala.aop.integration.steps",
                        "classpath:features/local/notify.feature"}
                , Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
```

And the feature is the follow:

```
Scenario: Notify on kafka
  Given "integration.test.in" topic destination to notify
  Then add message to notify
    |   field      |    value     |
    | test field   | value field  |
  And add header "headerTest" with value "integration.header"
  And notify kafka
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception

```
    This fallback has beep deprecated. Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.

For example:

   @@CucumberContextConfiguration
   @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
   public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { }
Or: 

   @@CucumberContextConfiguration
   @ContextConfiguration( ... )
   public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { }
F---

Failed scenarios:
classpath:features/local/notify.feature:17# Notify on kafka

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m0.105s


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pnc.aop.integration.steps.KafkaSteps.kafkaServerWithTopic(KafkaSteps.java:38)
```

Comment: What package is your `CucumberConfiguration` class in?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje ``ulala.aop.integration.boot`` into lib project

Comment: Which package are you passing as glue?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje The features are on main project, the steps are on external lib. the follow code is on main project ``new String[]{"--glue",
                        "ulala.aop.integration.steps",
                        "classpath:features/local/notify.feature"}``

Comment: Both the config and steps must be on the glue path. You only specify only one.

Comment: Alternatively don't provide glue, it defaults to the class path root and will pick up everything.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Hoiw can I fix that?

Comment: Hi, did you fix that?

Comment: @JehadNasser Yes. If you use ``Main.run`` you can not defined  ``CucumberOptions``. So i moved the step from libery dependencty to the main project and thats it